# Programatically access arbitrary web.config - can't access appSettings (app.config is fine)

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I'm accessing a config file thusly:

```
var map = new ConfigurationFileMap(configPath);
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(map);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("SomeSetting", "SomeValue");
```

It works fine for any .exe.config file, but not for any web.config.

Note: I am not trying to access the web.config of the current application, I am attempting to modify the web.config in an arbitrary path.

(I've tried `WebConfigurationManager` instead of `ConfigurationManager`, but it gives identical results)

The exception is thrown by the `AppSettings` property accessor - trying to `GetSection("appSettings")` and cast it to an `AppSettingsSection` of course gievs the same exception.  Either way, here it is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 'System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection'.
```

I have obviously searched around, but have found only people accessing the web.config for the 'current web app' or using `XmlDocument`/`XDocument`.

My guess is .exe.config files automatically get some configSections-type information inferred which means it correctly knows how to deal with appSettings.  However I have no idea why, based on the filename, it wouldn't work with web.config.

---

Ah.  For app.config I'm using OpenExeConfiguration:

```
// works fine for .exe.config
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("some-assembly-here.exe");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("SomeSetting", "SomeValue");
config.Save();
```

Here I'm using `OpenMappedMachineConfiguration` which appears to be for machine.config, however I can't see another way of opening an arbitrary web.config file - anyone?

Comment: So if you change the name of the web.config to web.exe.config then everything works as expected?

Comment: Huh, nope, same problem.  It could be because web.exe (or test.exe as I also tried test.exe.config) doesn't exist.. Nope, that's not it.  Let me see this difference between my configs...

Comment: [See latest edit: .exe.config I'm using a different method which works]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My mistake - I can use `OpenMappedExeConfiguration` just fine when opening web.config files:

```
            var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            map.ExeConfigFilename = configPath;
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```